# Convert DataFrame Index ('datetype') into Categorial Variable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing

Trying to generate categorial variables (numbers from 1 -365) for dates in one year which are in the index of a data frame.

Comment: Not sure you need a categorical dtype here, since the numbers are already integers. Perhaps just do [`df.index.dayofyear`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.dayofyear.html)

Comment: You can change type of a column by applying `df.A.astype("int32")`
If frame col is named A